# C Counter for characters for an input string gets random unwanted characters

Tags: arrays, c, string, random

I am trying to create a counter for an input string and it worked but it kept putting in random characters that weren't in the original input. For example: putting in ABC showed that the character V appeared 3 times which it obviously didn't. I know it has to do something with the input array but I don't know to properly fix it. writing "for(i = 0; i < sizeof(input)**-80**; i++) " fixed the issue but that's not really a good way to solve any problem.

Can someone please tell me the correct way to work with arrays?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
  char input[100];
  int i;
  int j;
  int k;
  char alphabet[52][2] = {{65,0},{66,0},{67,0},{68,0},{69,0},{70,0},{71,0},{72,0},{73,0},{74,0},{75,0},{76,0},{77,0},{78,0},{79,0},{80,0},{81,0},{82,0},{83,0},{84,0},{85,0},{86,0},{87,0},{88,0},{89,0},{90,0},{97,0},{98,0},{99,0},{100,0},{101,0},{102,0},{103,0},{104,0},{105,0},{106,0},{107,0},{108,0},{109,0},{110,0},{111,0},{112,0},{113,0},{114,0},{115,0},{116,0},{117,0},{118,0},{119,0},{120,0},{121,0},{122,0}}; //array for alphabet and counter in[1]

  printf("say something:\n");

  fgets(input, sizeof(input),stdin);

  for(i = 0; i < sizeof(input); i++)   
  {
    for(j = 0; j < 52; j++) 
    {
      if(input[i] == alphabet[j][0])  
        {
        alphabet[j][1]++;  
        }
    }
  }
  
  for(k = 0; k < 13; k++)
  {
    printf("amount %c: %d\t amount  %c: %d\t amount  %c: %d\t amount  %c: %d\n",alphabet[k][0],alphabet[k][1],alphabet[k+13][0],alphabet[k+13][1],alphabet[k+26][0],alphabet[k+26][1],alphabet[k+39][0],alphabet[k+39][1]); //output print
  }
}
```

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < sizeof(input); i++)` -> `for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)`. Because `sizeof` will give the full array including parts of it that have not been set. `strlen` will give just the string part.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: Note that white space is cheap and beneficial — your array definition could use spaces and newlines so it is all visible; ditto the `printf()` statement.  Your `for (j = 0; j < 52; j++)` loop could use a `break;` after the assignment in the `if` condition.

Comment: Calculating `strlen` every time around the loop is kinda pointless unless the compiler is clever enough to to detect that the string termination won't change and optimize the call down to a one-off.  But why call it at all?  `for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)`  Since you're obviously making a histogram here, you don't need to search the `alphabet` array if you use a few more bytes and just create a histogram: `int count[256] = {0};` -- then in your outer loop: `++count[(unsigned char)input[i]];`